# How to change cairo context source color for grayscale images

Tags: python, cairo, pycairo

I am trying to create images in greyscale using Cairo, however I am having issues control the pixel intensity of the pen.

For example in a RGB color image I would use this code to paint the background a shade of red with a pixel intensity of 127 in the red channel

```
surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_RGB24, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
ctx = cairo.Context(surface)
ctx.set_source_rgb(.5, 0, 0)
ctx.rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
ctx.fill()
```

I can't find any equilivant code for a grayscale image. 
I can't simply use the alpha channel because then I can't draw circles over rectangles. For example, take the below code snippet, where I would like to have:

- A grey background
- A black circle on top of the grey background

  `surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_A8, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
  ctx = cairo.Context(surface)
  ctx.set_source_rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
  ctx.rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
  ctx.fill()
  ctx.set_source_rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)
  ctx.arc(WIDTH//2, HEIGHT//2, r, 0, 2*math.pi)
  ctx.fill()`

In the above code, the black circle won't appear because it's alpha channel is lower than the gray background. How can I fix this?

Comment: What exactly is your goal in your second example? You use set_source_rgb, so have alpha=1 here. So, you are simply filling the surface with non-alpha. Does ctx.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_SOURCE) perhaps help you / do what you want?

Comment: Hey @UliSchlachter, I updated my post to contain more information about what I am trying to achieve, regarding `ctx.set_operator`, potentially OPERATOR_CLEAR might work. I will try it out and get back to you.
I wasn't aware of the `set_operator` method, thanks for bringing it up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the above code, the black circle won't appear because it's alpha channel is lower than the gray background.

The default operator is OVER, which overlay things. If you have some completely transparent overlay, then this overlay is, well, invisible. So, this is not because of the lower alpha channel. If you had a slightly higher alpha channel, let's say 0.5 and 0.1, the result would be an alpha channel with a value around 0.6 in the resulting image.

> How can I fix this?

```
surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_A8, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
ctx = cairo.Context(surface)
// I added the following line, but I am not sure about the syntax.
// In C, this would by cairo_set_operator(ctx, CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE);
ctx.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_SOURCE)
ctx.set_source_rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
ctx.rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
ctx.fill()
ctx.set_source_rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)
ctx.arc(WIDTH//2, HEIGHT//2, r, 0, 2*math.pi)
ctx.fill()
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. That's exactly what I wanted!
For anyone else curious you can read more about operators here: https://cairographics.org/operators/